# How to read files in HDFS in R without loosing column and row names

Tags: r, csv, hadoop, hdfs

My problem is that when I read a csv file containing column names for example (header), the names of the columns dissapear and have "V1","V2"... instead

I have the `mtcars` dataset in csv format and here is the preview

```
model,mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec,vs,am,gear,carb
Mazda RX4,21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
Mazda RX4 Wag,21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
Datsun 710,22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
```

I would like to upload to the HDFS and read it, so I go on the "HUE" platform and upload the file. I can view it in the file manager. here is a small preview:

[image]

Then in the R session using `plyrmr` I run the code hereafter:

```
filename3 <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars.csv"
input(filename3,format=make.input.format(format = "csv", sep=","))
```

and the result is this:

```
                V1   V2  V3    V4  V5   V6    V7    V8 V9 V10  V11  V12
1    Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8   440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0   0    3    4
2             Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08   2.2 19.47  1   1    4    1
3          Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1   1    4    2
4       Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835  19.9  1   1    4    1
```

As you can see the column names have gone away. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with `hdfs`, but can you not load the data with `read.csv(filename3, sep = ",", header = T)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found (I really don't like like it so if you have a better one please do share).

I separated the csv file in two csv files, one containing only the column names (mtcars_names.csv) and the other containing the data (mtcars_no_names.csv). Then uploaded them on the file manager.

```
filename <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars_no_names.csv"
filename.names <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars_names.csv"
filename.names <- as.data.frame(input(filename.names,
format=make.input.format(format = "csv", sep=",")))

# transform the columns in "character" types
for(i in 1:dim(filename.names)[2]){
  filename.names[,i] <- as.character(filename.names[,i])
}
```

Now everytime I write /read the file I code:

```
### comlumn name information is once more lost
output(input(filename,format=make.input.format(format = "csv",
sep=",", col.names = filename.names[1,])),
path="/user/sgerony/mtcars_output_csv")

input("/user/sgerony/mtcars_output_csv",
format=make.input.format(format = "csv", 
sep=",", col.names = filename.names[1,]))
```

which can get quite messy if I generate data subsets. For each subset with different column names a new file containing the column names will have to be generated