# convert csv in to native hadoop format

Tags: r, csv, hadoop, hdfs, hue

How can I convert a csv file in to the native hadoop format so that I can use it with the plyrmr package?

This question is related to another one of my posts:

[How to read files in HDFS in R without loosing column and row names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802116/how-to-read-files-in-hdfs-in-r-without-loosing-column-and-row-names)

I have the mtcars in csv format but when I read it with the following code it does not work:

```
filename3 <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars.csv" #file uploaded manually on to the HDFS
input(filename3) ## DOES NOT WORK
```

When I read it with the following code it works but I lose the column names:

```
input(filename3,format=make.input.format(format = "csv", sep=",")) ## works
```

Result:

```
                    V1   V2  V3    V4  V5   V6    V7    V8 V9 V10  V11  V12
1    Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8   440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0   0    3    4
2             Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08   2.2 19.47  1   1    4    1
3          Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1   1    4    2
4       Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835  19.9  1   1    4    1
```

This is already weird considering what the plyrmr tutorial on github shows.

So I was inspired by the following code that writes the mtcars in the HDFS and reads it back to see if the column names are preserved:

```
output(
      bind.cols(
        input(mtcars),
        carb.per.cyl = carb/cyl),
      path="/user/sgerony/mtcars0.out")
```

Result:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb carb.per.cyl
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    0.6666667
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    0.6666667
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    0.2500000
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    0.1666667
```

Then:

```
x=output(
      bind.cols(
        input(mtcars),
        carb.per.cyl = carb/cyl),
      path="/user/sgerony/mtcars0.out")
    get.format(x)
```

Result:

```
"native"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason I really do not understand I found a way to convert a csv to "native" format. So working with the mtcars dataset and separating it in to two csv files, one for the names (mtcars_names.csv) and one for the data (mtcars_no_names.csv):

```
filename <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars_no_names.csv"
filename.names <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars_names.csv"
filename.names <- as.data.frame(input(filename.names,
format=make.input.format(format = "csv", sep=",")))

for(i in 1:dim(filename.names)[2]){
  filename.names[,i] <- as.character(filename.names[,i])
}

output(input(filename,format=make.input.format(format = "csv",
  sep=",", col.names = filename.names[1,])),
  path="/user/sgerony/mtcars_output_csv")

#test the output
input("/user/sgerony/mtcars_output_csv",
  format=make.input.format(format = "csv", sep=","))
```

Result:

```
             V1 V2 V3  V4  V5   V6    V7    V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1    Datsun 710 22  4 108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1   1   4   1
2     Mazda RX4 21  6 160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0   1   4   4
3 Mazda RX4 Wag 21  6 160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0   1   4   4
```

As stated the column names dissapear, but now if I apply the bind.cols function for a reason I don't understand the output is in native format:

```
output(
  bind.cols(
    input("/user/sgerony/mtcars_no_names.csv",
format=make.input.format(format = "csv", sep=",", col.names = filename.names[1,])),
    carb.per.cyl = carb/cyl), 
  "/user/sgerony/mtcars1.out")
input("/user/sgerony/mtcars1.out")
```

Result:

```
          model mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb carb.per.cyl
1    Datsun 710  22   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    0.2500000
2     Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    0.6666667
3 Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    0.6666667
```

So it seems that the csv format is converted to native whenever a plyrmr function other then input and output is applied. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The code that "inspired you" does not ever use csv.

```
hexdump /tmp/mtcars0.out | head
0000000 94 00 00 00 00 93 00 00 01 6c 08 00 00 00 02 94
0000010 00 00 00 00 93 00 00 01 11 08 00 00 00 0c 91 00
0000020 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06
0000030 91 00 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00
0000040 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06 91 00
0000050 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06 91 00 00 00 01 06
0000060 91 00 00 00 01 06 92 00 00 00 26 00 00 00 03 07
0000070 00 00 00 05 6e 61 6d 65 73 07 00 00 00 09 72 6f
0000080 77 2e 6e 61 6d 65 73 07 00 00 00 05 63 6c 61 73
0000090 73 08 00 00 00 03 92 00 00 00 6e 00 00 00 0c 07
```

Try `make.input.format(format = "csv", sep = ",", col.names = names(mtcars))` Because of the way partitioned files are read, headers in csv are not supported, which means you have to remove them if present.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry but this is not the point. I was wondering if there was a way to transform the csv in to the native format so that I can keep the column names and not have to change my code a lot just for column name management.

I still have no clue why I can't get the same output as the plyrmr tutorial. Do you?

Comment: That's my best answer sorry. Avoid csv to preserve metadata.